# How to create a non-clustered index on a computed column in Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm calculating value of a column from another column and I need to create a non-clustered index on the calculated column.

When I try to specify index on the calculated column using Entity Framework, system throws an exception

> An exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Filtered index 'UK_ProdBarCode_BarCodeNumber' cannot be created on table 'ProdBarCode' because the column 'BarCodeNumber' in the filter expression is a computed column. Rewrite the filter expression so that it does not include this column.

```
prodbarcode.Property<long>(ProdBarCode => 
       ProdBarCode.BarCodeNumber).HasComputedColumnSql("CAST(BarCode AS Bigint)");

prodbarcode.HasIndex(ProdBarCode => 
       new { ProdBarCode.BarCodeNumber })
      .HasName("UK_ProdBarCode_BarCodeNumber")
      .IsUnique(true)
      .ForSqlServerIsClustered(false);
```

Comment: _"Unfortunately as of SQL Server 2014, there is no ability to create a Filtered Index where the Filter is on a Computed Column (regardless of whether or not it is persisted)."_ - [Unable to create a Filtered Index on a Computed Column](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/116348/2325)

Comment: Yes, it is impossible to create a filtered index on a computed column, but the apposite question is probably: why is EF trying to build a *filtered* index? I see nothing in that definition that includes a filter, and creating a unique index on a computed column otherwise works fine (e.g. `CREATE TABLE #a(BarCode INT, BarCodeNumber AS CAST(BarCode AS BIGINT)); CREATE UNIQUE INDEX IX_#a_ProdBarCode ON #a(BarCodeNumber);`; add `WHERE BarCodeNumber IS NOT NULL` to get an error).

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem today. Unfortunately, I wasn't able to find any information on this from Entity Framework or Microsoft. However, I did find a workaround for my situation.

If you add a filter yourself, and target the source column or columns, it should accomplish the same effect and it is valid SQL. See updated code below...

```
prodbarcode.Property<long>(ProdBarCode => 
       ProdBarCode.BarCodeNumber)
       .HasComputedColumnSql("CAST(BarCode AS Bigint)");

prodbarcode.HasIndex(ProdBarCode => 
       new { ProdBarCode.BarCodeNumber })
      .HasName("UK_ProdBarCode_BarCodeNumber")
      .IsUnique(true)
      .HasFilter($"{nameof(ProdBarCode.BarCode)} IS NOT NULL") // <-- filter on source field
      .ForSqlServerIsClustered(false);
```